# Making a link pulled from a database active

Tags: database, hyperlink, echo

I'm creating a social network, and in the user info section I've made it possible for the user to add there Facebook link into the database table via a input form. 
Now when they add this link, it sends it to the database and then it returns and echo's out the submitted data into both the user info page and the user status stream, this enables others can see there newly updated info.

Only problem is, the link submitted is not active when it returns from the database, is there anyway either in my page, or within the database, I can tell this to be an active link, maybe even some JavaScript that detects inactive links?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "make the link active"?

What language are you developing in?

To use a database field to generate a clickable link in a web browser, you create the HTML framework and then insert the database output into the relevant position.

In PHP, for instance:

```
<a href="<?php echo $linkURL;?>"><?php echo $linkURL; ?></a>
```

Would create a clickable link which would direct visitors to the URL in the `$linkURL` variable.

Comment: Exactly that, the link in putted into the database through a text form prints out an inactive link (just the text form) in both the user info area and the users feed. I just want to make it active somehow. And I'm Php

Comment: As example - When adding a link into Facebooks about section, when you submit it, it automatically turns active. My link isn't doing that atm.

Comment: Php that calls for the info to print it out

$response['user_facebooklink']  = stripslashes($echo['user_facebooklink']);


Form code that is printed out from the database

<tr><td align="left">Facebook:       <td align="left"><input type='text' value='<?php echo $user['user_facebooklink'] ?>'  name='set_facebook'>

Comment: @David Draw: OK, trying to understand what you are saying here, but you are not terribly clear. What is the actual HTML being output by the page? The technique I mention above does work (has every time I have used it), so it must be something in the data stored in your database, or the format of same when you are echoing it.